# In ansible version 2.9.25 - how to tar, compress (gzip) the directory in Linux and copy to destination path

Tags: ansible, copy, gzip, tar

In ansible version 2.9.25 - how to create tar file of given dir and also compress (gzip) that dir in Linux (RHEL 7.9) to the given destination path directly. During Oracle DB patching as pre-check task, I want to take backup of existing oraInventory dir to the destination path. oraInventory is always under /u01/app dir in all Linux servers. I have already tried the community.general.archive but it is not working properly in "ansible version 2.9.25".

at present - Manually I used to run below command which creates tar file of oraInventory and gzip to the destination path (/dbbackup)

cd /u01/app
tar -pczvf /dbbackup/Backup_OraInv_<SID_NAME>.tar oraInventory | gzip > /dbbackup/Backup_OraInv_<SID_NAME>.tar.gz

Please help for this code.

I have already tried the community.general.archive but it is not working properly in "ansible version 2.9.25".

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what "_is not working properly_" means? Are there error message? How the result looks like? Can you furthermore share your playbook which you have tried already?

Comment: Hi @U880D Please find below my code and error details. 
Code ==>
 - name: Take backup of Oracle Inventory in tar & gz format.
    archive:
    path: "/u01/app/oraInventory"
    dest: "/dbbackup"
    format: gz

Error: ====>
ERROR! conflicting action statements: dest, path

The error appears to be in '/home/yogeshka/DB_tools/ansible/db_server_new/roles/oracle_patch/tasks/main.yml': line 79, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


  - name: Take backup of Oracle Inventory in tar & gz format.

Comment: Instead of pasting code unformatted into a comment, can you update your initial question by editing? Furthermore, were you able to look into the example?

Comment: Ok sure. Yeah! the given links regarding "community.general.archive:" examples that I already checked before opening thread here. As I searched and  found on net community.general.archive: does not work for the  ansible version 2.9.25. This I mentioned in my very first comment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the documentation [`archive` module – Creates a compressed archive of one or more files or trees](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html) and [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/archive_module.html#examples), a minimal playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - archive:
      path: "/home/user/test/toarchive/"
      dest: "backup.tar.gz"
      format: gz
      force_archive: true
```

will result into a `backup.tar.gz` file having the requested content

```bash
tar -tvf backup.tar.gz
```

To summarize, based on the currently given information not able to (re-)produce an issue.

Comment: In your above code what is the value of dest: "backup.tar.gz". Does it will create tar.gz file at specific location or at current location only?  I am looking for backup file should be created under specific filesystem that is under /dbbackup location so in my code - I have given FS path.

Comment: The value of of the key:value pair `dest: "backup.tar.gz"` is `backup.tar.gz`. It will create the file at the current location. "_I am looking for backup file should be created under specific_", then just provide the path `/dbbackup/backup.tar.gz`.